# nodemon to exec "prestart" script at package.json

Tags: node.js, webpack, nodemon

I want to setup nodemon to run the **"prestart"** script when server restarts, the reason, I'm using webpack and I want to build *bundle.js* every time a file changes, I'm not using `webpack-dev-server` cause I don't know how to set it up with an existing node app running, I got my backend on `node.js`, help on that will be appreciated.

The way I've been working is: run `npm start` every time I make a change on the code, but that too much effort.

Here's the `scripts` object at *package.json* so that you have an idea of what's going on:

```
"scripts": {
    "bundle": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "prestart": "npm run bundle",
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The way I've accomplished to do that is by **creating a `nodemon.json`** file with the **`exec`** property:

```
 {
    // ... Other conf (see an example in https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md)
    "watch": [
      "app" // Set your directories/files to watch
    ],
    "exec": "npm run prestart && node server/index.js"
 }
```